# No version of openssl is available because of a conflict

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use openssl:

```
# Cargo.toml
openssl = "0.10.4"
```

Error:

```
error: failed to select a version for `openssl-sys` (required by `openssl`):
all possible versions conflict with previously selected versions of `openssl-sys`
version 0.9.24 in use by openssl-sys v0.9.24
possible versions to select: 0.9.26
```

Ok, I'm trying 0.9.26

```
# Cargo.toml
openssl = "0.9.26"
```

And:

```
error: no matching version `^0.9.26` found for package `openssl` (required by `test1_app`)
location searched: registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
versions found: 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2, ...
```

Comment: That error message is not about `openssl`, it's referring to `openssl-sys`.  Depending on `openssl` directly works just fine for me, which suggests that you're depending on *more* than just `openssl`, or you've got some other constraint somewhere you haven't mentioned.

Comment: `possible versions to select: 0.9.26` refers to the version of `openssl-sys` that is referenced by openssl. Try using openssl version 0.9.23 it seems to reference `openssl-sys` version 0.9.24 that is suggested see [here](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/blob/9a27bb2c032b666fc7dc607a804f8dc144959034/openssl/Cargo.toml)